# onChange on file input not firing after invoked with SPACE or ENTER

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chromium, onchange

I have a react component that displays an img tag and allows the user to choose an image from their computer to display in it. The component works well on all browsers, except on Chromium based browsers (tested it on Chrome, Chromium, Brave, Firefox and Epiphany).

The issue is that when the user clicks on the img tag using the spacebar or enter key (for accessibility purposes) and then chooses an image, the img tag doesn't change (the onChange on the file input doesn't trigger). However, when the user clicks on the img tag normally (with a mouse), the image changes successfully (in all browsers).

I'm using the useRef and useState hooks to manage the state of the component, and the onChange event to detect when the user has chosen an image. There are no console errors.

The code:

```
function Avatar() {
  const inputRef = useRef(null)
  const [imageSrc, setImageSrc] = useState('https://fastly.picsum.photos/id/605/200/200.jpg?hmac=aAxC3x4fmu7RXhLH-1idijrAUvlZVEwlUqjzKR80YWo')

  const handleImageChange = (event) => {
    console.log('HANDLE IMAGE CHANGE')
    const file = event.target.files[0]
    const reader = new FileReader()
    reader.readAsDataURL(file)
    reader.onload = () => {
      setImageSrc(reader.result)
    }
  }

  const handleImageClick = () => {
    inputRef.current.click()
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <img
        tabIndex="0"
        src={imageSrc}
        alt="avatar"
        onClick={handleImageClick}
        onKeyDown={(e) => {
          if (e.code === 'Tab') return

          e.preventDefault()

          if (['Enter', 'Space'].includes(e.code)) handleImageClick()
        }}
      />
      <input type="file" ref={inputRef} style={{ display: 'none' }} onChange={handleImageChange} />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Also, there's a [live version of it](https://codepen.io/jofko_/pen/rNZwrmQ).

Any idea what could be causing this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap around the img with the button tag. The button tag will cover all your accessibility issues. You just need to add styling as per your requirement

```
 return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleImageClick} style={{border:'none', background: 'transparent'}}>
          <img
            src={imageSrc}
            alt="avatar"
          />
      </button>
      <input type="file" ref={inputRef} style={{ display: 'none' }} onChange={handleImageChange} />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Here is the live example https://codepen.io/jainshubh/pen/JjaJaME

Comment: A good solution but still makes me wonder what's with the Chromium browsers?